# Alternatives for "installed" when referring to a food establishment

Tags: word-choice

> Caroline wondered whether there were coffee shops and restaurants in other
>   galaxies. She imagined them **installed** on floating asteroids, or in the
>   rest area of cosmic highways. Since the universe was so infinitely
>   large, how couldn't there be at least one or two?

Is **installed** a good term to use in this case? If not, are there other better options?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on- or off-topic, but you could try _"She imagined them **opened for business** on floating asteroids..."_ Or, perhaps even better, forego the word "them", and say, _"She imagined bustling cafés on floating asteroids..."_

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the suggestion. How about *opening* or just *opened* (without the business part)?

Comment: Sure, you could say that, but _open_ has a lot of different meanings, (as in, _open-air_). It could mean the doors were open, the roof was open, or that the establishments were out in the open. You get a shorter sentence, but you might introduce some ambiguity. It's a tradeoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a word in your question that would work just fine.

[Established](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/established)

1. a. To set up; found. 
   b. To bring about; generate: establish goodwill in the neighborhood.
2. a. To place or settle in a secure position or condition; install: They established me in my own business.
   b. To make firm or secure.

This works especially well for smaller businesses (like diners and such) since the entire business would be established on these little out-of-the-way locations, and I imagine that's exactly the kind of evokation you're going for, though this now verges on writing advice rather than grammar advice.

Answer (score 2):

- *Located* is one option - perhaps a bit technical-sounding.
- *Sited*
- You could expand a little based around *serving* ("She imagined them serving soy caramel lattes* to little green men on floating asteroids")
- You could use a rather more figurative term, such as *standing* (related to a question yesterday, maybe yours)

J.R.'s suggestion of avoiding "them" would get my vote if it were an answer.

*because you'd need to be an alien to want one.

Answer (score 2):

"...that little bistro [ensconced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ensconce) on [Vesta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_Vesta). I forget the name, but you know the place."